# Login to mobile app and web app using oAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0

We have a SSO system which is used by our web applications and we are planning to also write some new mobile/desktop applications. I have been reading about using oAuth 2.0 so a user can natively login using the app (using the password grant type), retrieve an access token and access functionality using the REST web services. The problem is all functionality will not be available within the app, in some cases we have to redirect the user to the web application via a browser. I have read we shouldn't pass the access token in a URL so is there anyway to use oAuth to login to the web application automatically without the user having to submit their username and password again?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the mobile app, you could create a nonce (a token that should be used no more than once). Then, add this to the URL when opening a link to the Web page. This token should have some sort of identifier in it. The Web app that serves that page should track these IDs to ensure that it's not sent multiple times (thus, making it a nonce). This would be independent of the OAuth-based authentication. So, a request might look like this:

```
GET /anything?nonce=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI5N1Y2ZU9WWlo1VGpPR3dWIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoibXktZ29vZC1tb2JpbGUtYXBwLTIyIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9leGFtcGxlLm9yZy9wYWdlLXRoYXQtaXMtbm90LWluLW15LW1vYmlsZS1hcHAiLCJleHAiOjE1OTg3NTI0NDB9.JoDstXRnC23PE8ZCqk-U-IzSNp_cUYa12HbajI1KGlF-OwRR46QRC_V7brcGOVdo5_Aw1RdpssNWCVFiGDeTBc8wi1lIJW-rgEGH5J1qUi8rL1T-yfy3vdLGPYzJMtHvCeyoEjgmoYOtZcpPSQScBJSRvId3Hdu3QgwcelSwljkeNJbZRCnG25HIqJfC1Cjm9vqHhvUGqtzbgVBUPnICiI8EZyGe3SpH2P4SxctLcgzWad8zJeyPFki3yfBHpqQ3mBWy0BbVdjzgD0mj323q1LWHR4kNkrH7cUJgAg4PlWahOW7Q4qcT3CBJYNtlh008ARqK7XagEQKX45vv5TfSlk2q7Zy06RnV2XwZXfLpyh-ZfURpcsxEJ3O-4NY71XxEqUtEyuisjQdZx5m95uzSrzk75F-ruQ3KYIouiAOAUDuMtFwhwjF68VdDeC4Zwt2q3BHzMBBp-8k1bAXq8e4dmHz0Jbuo9R8MJ2zSrVK6is5nNtNoJvYoXgc0WTA8MFqBj316cT_ouu-U1nTL3GR5sJ_lxorhP6xz0CqNxNY_90-JwOUB0UibUryRiXt-SUPJga36pBQ8eO8--Xupx_WU7CDIFdFvnLgJahD-4KmZcga6wCoqd-KKw3H5-jtbit06XMrKkDiWjz2g4eYhPR6xipbnqyZaaCwtYN4mAMz86ug HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Accept: */*
```

When the JWT-encoded nonce is decoded, you can see this header:

```
{
  "alg": RS256
}
```

and this body:

```
{
  "jti": "97V6eOVZZ5TjOGwV",
  "client_id": "my-good-mobile-app-22",
  "aud": "https://example.org/page-that-is-not-in-my-mobile-app",
  "exp": 1598752440
}
```

Now, the API could decide if the nonce is acceptable by:

1. Check that it's URL is the same as the `aud` (audience) claim
2. Check that the nonce has never been seen before (using the `jti`, JWT ID, claim)
3. Check that this resource should be possible for this client to request (using the `client_id` claim)
4. Check that the nonce wasn't created too long ago and is still valid (using the `exp` or expires claim)
5. The signature of the JWT is valid. This can be done using the public key of the client.

Doing like this could lead to a spaghetti of trust, however. To avoid this, your OAuth server could instead embed a nonce into the app's ID token, or allow the client to request new ones as needed (by performing token exchange e.g.). Then, the API only has to trust the OAuth server, and doesn't need to keep track of the client's public key. If you only have a handful of clients, this won't be hard to mange though.